# let $f(x) = (x-1)\ln x$, and given $0 < a < b$. If $f(a) = f(b)$, prove that $\frac{1}{\ln a}+\frac{1}{\ln b} < \frac{1}{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Let $f(x) = (x-1)\ln x$, and given $0 < a < b$.

If $f(a) = f(b)$, how to prove that $\frac{1}{\ln a}+\frac{1}{\ln b} < \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: This one has kept me going for quite a while. Playing around in DESMOS, is it possible that the $1/2$ should have an inclusion sign? I think this is a great question, wondering why it has had so few "viewers"

Comment: @imranfat Thank you for your attention. it just $<$, not $\le$.

Comment: Well, I am keen to see an answer, and since you tagged it without Calculus, I am even more interested in an answer! With programming I can see it work, but that ain't no proof

Comment: Wait, if $b>a \Rightarrow \ln b > \ln a\ \&\ (b-1)>(a-1) \Rightarrow (b-1) \ln b > (a-1) \ln a \Rightarrow f(b)>f(a)$?

Comment: @SuhridSaha the second $\Rightarrow$ is not right. because $a-1$ and $\ln a$ can both $< 0$. You can plot the pic of $f(x)$, then you will see the $a,b$ there.

Comment: @xunitc Oh yeah, i really make such stupid mistakes :P

Answer (score 3):

**Proof.**

Let $f(x) = (x-1)\ln x$.
Clearly, $f(1) = 0$, $\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} f(x) = \infty$, and $\lim_{x\to \infty} = \infty$.
We have $f'(x) = \ln x + 1 - \frac{1}{x}$. Clearly, $f(x)$ is strictly decreasing on $(0, 1)$, and strictly increasing on $(1, \infty)$. Thus, $0 < a < 1$ and $1 < b$.

We have
$$
\frac{1}{\ln a} + \frac{1}{\ln b} = \frac{a-1}{(a-1)\ln a} + \frac{b-1}{(b-1)\ln b} = \frac{a+b-2}{(b-1)\ln b}.
$$
It suffices to prove that
$$a < \frac{1}{2}(b-1)\ln b - b + 2. \tag{1}$$
We split into two cases:

1. $b \ge \mathrm{e}^2$: Then $\frac{1}{2}(b-1)\ln b - b + 2 \ge 1$. Clearly, (1) is true.
2. $1 < b < \mathrm{e}^2$: It is not difficult to prove that $0 < \frac{1}{2}(b-1)\ln b - b + 2 < 1$.
   Since $f(x)$ is strictly decreasing on $(0, 1)$, it suffices to prove that
   $$f(a) > f(\tfrac{1}{2}(b-1)\ln b - b + 2)$$
   or
   $$f(b) > f(\tfrac{1}{2}(b-1)\ln b - b + 2)$$
   or
   $$(b-1)\ln b - \left(\tfrac{1}{2}(b-1)\ln b - b + 1\right)\ln \left( \tfrac{1}{2}(b-1)\ln b - b + 2 \right) > 0$$
   or
   $$\frac{1}{2}(b-1)\left[ 2\ln b + (2 - \ln b)\ln \left(1 - \tfrac{1}{2}(b-1)(2-\ln b)\right)\right]  > 0.$$
   It suffices to prove that
   $$2\ln b + (2 - \ln b)\ln \left(1 - \tfrac{1}{2}(b-1)(2-\ln b)\right) > 0.$$
   Let $b = \mathrm{e}^y$. Then $0 < y < 2$. It suffices to prove that
   $$2y + (2-y)\ln \left(1 - \tfrac{1}{2}(\mathrm{e}^y-1)(2-y)\right) > 0$$
   or
   $$\frac{2y}{2-y} + \ln \left(1 - \tfrac{1}{2}(\mathrm{e}^y-1)(2-y)\right) > 0.$$
   Denote the LHS by $g(y)$. We have
   $$g'(y) = \frac{(y^3-5y^2+12y-12)\mathrm{e}^y - y^2 + 12}{(2-y)^2(2 - (\mathrm{e}^y-1)(2-y))}.$$
   It is not difficult to prove that $(y^3-5y^2+12y-12)\mathrm{e}^y - y^2 + 12 > 0$
   for all $y$ in $(0, 2)$.
   Thus, $g'(y) > 0$ for all $y$ in $(0, 2)$. Also, $g(0) = 0$.
   Thus, $g(y) > 0$ for all $y$ in $(0, 2)$.

We are done.

Comment: Nice answer even if it's not very elegant .(+1)

Comment: @Mister.Expandead  Thank you!

Comment: Thank you. I see the function's pic and the expression are both so "symmetrical", I think there maybe an elegant solve.

Comment: @xunitc   Hope to see elegant solution.